# Including template inside global template in VBulletin

Tags: templates, include, vbulletin

I need to do something like this in VBulletin.
There should be several templates (I added them through admincp), that should be "included" in the global template called **"footer"**. In fact only one of them should be included depending on somecondition.
So in this **footer** I have

```
<vb:if condition="$my_variable == 1">
    <p>CASE_1</p>
<vb:elseif condition="$my_variable == 2" />
    <p>CASE_2</p>
<vb:else />
    <p>CASE_3</p>
</vb:if>
```

So in this if cases I need to change the CASE-s with a code to include other templates (i.e. "footer1", "footer2", "footer3").

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So, isn't there a way to include templates in existing templates???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have done this by creating a template, passing the variables to it, rendering it and preregistering in the footer template like this (class_bootstrap.php):

```
$templater = vB_Template::create('footer_'.$extension);
$templater->register('admincpdir', $admincpdir);
...

$includable_footer = $templater->render();
vB_Template::preRegister('footer',array('included_footer ' => $includable_footer));

$templater = vB_Template::create('footer');
$templater->register('included_footer', $includable_footer);
$footer = $templater->render();
```

And in the footer template inserted this line:

```
{vb:raw included_footer}
```